# Pacman -R: Removing package errors on cyclic dependency

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

When I try to remove some packages, I get this error:

```
╰─ sudo pacman -R avahi               
[sudo] password for laith: 
checking dependencies...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: geoclue: removing avahi breaks dependency 'avahi'
:: gvfs: removing avahi breaks dependency 'avahi'
:: libcups: removing avahi breaks dependency 'avahi'
:: libdmapsharing: removing avahi breaks dependency 'avahi'
```

This look erroneous to me- Pacman doesn't want to break a dependency of the package I want to remove. Am I misunderstanding something here, or is there a way to tell pacman this is ok?

Comment: I have actually just installed it in an effort to connect to my office printer. It's not just avahi I have this trouble with, I get this issue when I try to remove haskell/ghc-libs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A package in Arch Linux commonly declares a dependency on other packages because of one or more features that are needed by a package and provided by another, such as shared objects (files whose names are suffixed by `.so`). This is a concept of a dependency tree, which is common to many other GNU/Linux distributions.

The error you are experiencing does not denote a cyclic dependency. `pacman` output is actually saying that you are trying to remove a feature that four packages depend on. For example, the message `gvfs: removing avahi breaks dependency 'avahi'` means that:

- The `avahi` package provides the `avahi` feature.
- The `gvfs` packages depends on the `avahi` feature. Features provided by `gvfs` will not work well without it.
- You tried to remove `avahi` package, which is currently the only package that provides the `avahi` feature.
- In order to avoid a dependency tree break, `pacman` prevented you from removing `avahi` package.

Usually, package names match feature names, however there are some exceptions. For example, [`beanshell`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/beanshell/) package depends on `java-runtime` feature, which is provided by [`jre8-openjdk`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/jre8-openjdk/), [`jre10-openjdk`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/jre10-openjdk/) and several other packages.

When `pacman` identifies a potential dependency tree break, you are required to tell the package manager how to deal with it. I see the following options:

- Tell `pacman` to remove the `avahi` package and all packages which depends on features being removed by specifying the `--cascade` argument:

```
    $ sudo pacman -R --cascade avahi
```

- Tell `pacman` to ignore the dependency tree at all by specifying the `--nodeps` argument twice:

```
    $ sudo pacman -R --nodeps --nodeps avahi
```

---

References:

- [pacman (8)](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html)
- [pacman - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman)